# How can I install Laravel 9.4.1 version?

Tags: laravel

I want to install Laravel 9.4.1 in my system but it is installing 9.3.0 automatically when I write this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel newproject
```

I have am using PHP 8.1.6.

Comment: use `composer create-project laravel/laravel newproject 9.4`

Comment: no its not working

Comment: I think you have confused the laravel framework version ([repo here](https://github.com/laravel/framework)) with the laravel boilerplate application version ([repo here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)). The latest boilerplate application version is 9.3 but it should install the latest framework version when installed. The version number in the boilerplate application is just for reference, you're expected to modify it to add your own code in it and at that point it diverges from what's in github

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^9.3.8 <your_name_project>
```

the latest version is 9.3.8

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 9.4.1 version has not been released, so it's wise not to install.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel newproject
```

This command automatically installs a supported project using the Laravel framework, and this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.3.8 your-project-name
```

Installs the 9.3.8 Laravel LTS version.